# Is it Safe to Use "ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.xx" Command for IP Addresses Which are Faced With UFW_BLOCK?

Tags: mariadb, ufw, ubuntu-20.04, galera

I have UFW opened on my database servers and I have seen a lot of UFW_BLOCK logs. Is it safe or right to use "ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.xx" and "ufw allow to xx.xx.xx.xx" command for all IP addresses which are blocked? I have allowed blocked IP addresses with port 112 on iptables but I am confused which is the best practise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow an IP address on a spesific port, you should use iptables, otherwise you can use either "UFW allow from-to" or iptables, doesn't matter. I have allowed all coming blocked IP addresses in iptables.